# What is the significance of the colour of the sashes the Tracy boys wear?

Tags: thunderbirds, gerry-anderson

In the below image you will note that each of the Tracy Boys wear a different colour sash.  That's understandable.  Scott (who pilots Thunderbird 1) wears a blue sash.  Thunderbird 1's 'colour' is blue.  That makes sense.  As soon as we cross to Virgil, who wears a yellow sash, we find that the colour of the Thunderbird they pilot is not consistent with their sash colour (Thunderbird 2 is green of course).  Hence I am wondering if there is any significance to the colour of their sashes and, if so, what is that.  I would prefer an in-universe answer, but if there is none (which I fear may be the case), I will happily accept an out-of-universe answer.

[image: Tracy Boys' sashes]

Comment: Out of universe, I'd guess that the primary reason was to immediately distinguish extremely similar looking puppets to the audience.

Comment: It appears to be personal choice. Brains and Jeff both wear a brown sash when the need arises

Comment: I always suspected there would be some relation to their personal choices @Richard; I've just never been able to find evidence to support that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a theory, but a promising one.

When one looks closely at each of these five characters and the craft they pilot, one realises that each craft has a trim color which **matches** the color of their sash!

- Thunderbird 1 has a 'trim' color of blue by the base of the rocket
- Thunderbird 2 has a 'trim' color of yellow around the edges where the pod docks
- Thunderbird 3 has a 'trim' color of white around the ends of the rockets
- Thunderbird 4 has a 'trim' color of orange around the front of the craft
- Thunderbird 5 has a 'trim' color of a purple below the number '5'

I've included a picture to support this contention:

[image: Highlighting of Trims]

Comment: Apologies about the poor picture of TB5!

Comment: Unless they got the trim first and then did the paint jobs...

Comment: TB4's 'orange' stripes are actually red; I guess they look orange in this picture but in pretty much any other picture they're red. My answer is that Gordon thought orange stripes didn't look good so he decided to make them red (I'm going under the assumption that their sashes are coloured to their favorite colours and for the primary colour of the craft they just chose something that goes well with or multiple colours that look they good with such as with TB5. I'm also guessing that Gordon couldn't find a colour to go with orange and he ended up just choosing that for the colour scheme. I muc