# What is Thunderbird 5's color?

Tags: thunderbirds, gerry-anderson

Every *Thunderbirds* fan knows that each of the Thunderbird vehicles has a distinct color e.g. Thunderbird 2's 'color' is green, made obvious by its mainly being green.  Each of the Thunderbirds (including FAB 1) colors is made very obvious, except for Thunderbird 5.  It does not really feature a main color (see image below) or a significant color as is the case with Thunderbird 1 which is mainly silver/grey with the blue base.  Hence, what is Thunderbird 5's color?

[image: Thunderbird 5]

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/81833/13024

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## It turns out that Thunderbird 5's color is red

I come to this conclusion on the basis of this image:
[image: image showing colors of Thunderbirds]
This image is taken from the film *Thunderbirds Are Go!* at the very beginning (I don't recall the exact point in time, but it was within the first 20 seconds at the beginning of the actual movie).

You will observe five colors, each representing a different vehicle:

- Blue (Thunderbird 1)
- Green (Thunderbird 2)
- Orange (Thunderbird 3)*
- Yellow (Thunderbird 4)

The only remaining color is red.  Since there are five Thunderbirds, and the last color is not pink (which would indicate FAB 1), it is reasonable to assume this must be assigned to Thunderbird 5.  Hence Thunderbird 5's 'color' must be red!

This is not such a ridiculous idea, as if you look closely at the image in the original question, you will note that there is red present on the Thunderbird just below the '5' near the docking port.

*There is some confusion about Thunderbird 3's color.  I always thought it was red and many pictures suggest it is indeed red (take a look at the [Thunderbird 3 page](http://thunderbirds.wikia.com/wiki/Thunderbird_3) on the *Thunderbirds* Wiki for examples).  However, according to *[The Complete Book of Thunderbirds](http://thunderbirds.wikia.com/wiki/The_Complete_Book_of_Thunderbirds)* 40th Edition (Bentley, 2006), at the top of page 47 (the page on Thunderbird 3) it clearly states (bold is my emphasis):

> Thunderbird 3 is International Rescue's massive **orange** space rocket.

This is what I base my argument on.

Comment: Hm, my conclusion would be that the writer calls the red line "orange", and that the other line signifies TB5. Maybe they would call it "gold". See also your photo of the TB5. Definitely gold!

Comment: @Mr Lister; there is only one yellow/golden line which would be attributed to TB4, so I am not quite sure where you are coming from?

Comment: Ehm, I wasn't looking at the yellow line. I was trying to say that the red line, for TB3, might be called "orange" by the writer, so that would leave the orange line for TB5. Which would then mean that the orange line couldn't be called "orange".

Comment: @MrLister interesting point, although I would have thought that the line I call red would commonly be interpreted as red.